# String[] does not contain the definition for ToArray() and no extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to store selected checkboxes values using StringBuilder and foreach loop, then convert it into the string array.

Here is my code

```
public ActionResult Home(CheckList obj)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
        foreach (var item in obj.Checkboxes)
        {
            if (item.IsChecked)
                sb.Append(item.Value).ToString();

        }

       string[] col = sb.ToString().Split(' ').ToArray();

 ..
}
```

But I got an error on this line of no definition of ToArray() to String[]

```
string[] col = sb.ToString().Split(' ').ToArray();
```

Kindly help me how can I change my string into a string array.

Comment: Why are you converting an array to array? You don't need to. it is already an array!

Comment: you are already getting an array when you split it

Comment: you need add `using System.Linq;` but how said @Sweeper `Split` returns an array

Comment: As `.Split()` returns an array, You don't need `.ToArray()`. Just remove it

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for the help I got your point.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see here in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___), `Split` already returns a string array.

Comment: `Split` does return array but that's not the question, at best this should have been the comment

Answer (score 3):

`ToArray()` method is included in [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.8), so simply using linq should work:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer doesn't contain anything, that isn't already included in the question.

Comment: In agreement. the answer is correct for the question. He can not use `ToArray()` because he is missing using `System.Linq`. That he would like to make an unnecessary conversion is something else

Comment: @schlonzo The question doesn't include anything about "using" statement. If you're about the comment under the question, in Stackoverflow, comments are not the place for providing answers. Also, that comment was made after this answer  :)

Comment: @JustShadow That's true, but including a `using` statement is trivial and it doesn't solve the problem to the question...

Comment: This is in fact the only answer which suggest the solution to the exact issue that OP is pointing to, even if that question is incorrect and does Array to Array conversion, +1, this is pointless down voting and @JustShadow, so add more details, like documentation details, extension method, since this could have been just comment

Comment: @asd How do you know that `System.Linq` is missing. He didn't mention any of the `using`s that are necessary for running the snippet.

Comment: @schlonzo the title is "String[] does not contain the definition for ToArray()". this message is displayed when `using System.Linq;` is not added.

Comment: @asd OK, you are right. I'm glad I didn't downvote. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

str.Split return an array of string. No need to convert it again to Array.

```
string str = sb.ToString();
string[] col = null;
int count = 0;
char[] splitchar = { ' ' };
col = str.Split(splitchar);
```